# UIScrollview scrolls but does not stay where users lifts finger swift Storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiscrollview, storyboard

I have a UIView with a set of images labels and what not that I have embed into a scrollview. the Scrollview does scroll but when the user lifts their finger, the scrollview bounces back to the beginning. I want it to stay when the user lifts their finger. There is not code involved with this, it just pure storyboard action.

The UIView is larger than the scrollview. And the Scrollview is set to the size of the main view. 
Any suggestions on how to keep it from bouncing?

Comment: Can you paste a screenshot of your storyboard?

Comment: couple of questions , are you using autolayout , are you using scrollview delegate methods, have you set content size or content offset manually

Comment: This looks like the same issue as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39560586/updated-after-swift-3-update-uiscrollview-not-scrolling-even-when-contentsize). In my case, it ended up being an iOS 10-only issue. I still haven't solved it.

Answer (score 1):

In UIview connect the last uielememt to top layoutguide and bottom layout guide.And another thing your content should be greater than selecting device, try.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you dont set contentsize for scroll view yet.

Answer (score 1):

OK. It may very well be [the same problem that I had](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39560586/updated-after-swift-3-update-uiscrollview-not-scrolling-even-when-contentsize).

If that is the case, you need to mark ALL of your autolayout constraints in the scrolled (the one inside the scroller) view as "remove at build time."

Looks like iOS10 is now insisting that setting "0" as the distance from top or leading MEANS "0," and will keep snapping the view back to the top.

In my case, this did not happen in iOS 9, but started happening in iOS 10.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling "paging enabled"?
I think if you get your `UIScrollView` scrolling! that's your problem