# iOS 10 Issue: UIScrollView Not Scrolling, Even When ContentSize Is Set

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiscrollview

***UPDATE:*** This is an iOS 10 issue. This still works as before in iOS 9.

This is ...interesting.

I just converted my "teaching project" (a "toy" app) to Swift 3.

It has been working for a couple of years under Swift 1.2.

All of a sudden, my UIScrollView is not scrolling, even when I set the contentSize way past its lower boundary.

Here's the relevant code (the displayTags routine is called with an array of images that are displayed centered and slightly vertically offset, leading to a vertical chain):

```
    /*******************************************************************************************/
    /**
        \brief  Displays the tags in the scroll view.

        \param inTagImageArray the array of tag images to be displayed.
    */
    func displayTags ( inTagImageArray:[UIImage] )
    {
        self.tagDisplayView!.bounds = self.tagDisplayScroller!.bounds
        if ( inTagImageArray.count > 0 )    // We need to have images to display
        {
            var offset:CGFloat = 0.0    // This will be the vertical offset for each tag.

            for tag in inTagImageArray
            {
                self.displayTag ( inTag: tag, inOffset: &offset )
            }
        }
    }
    /*******************************************************************************************/
    /**
        \brief  Displays a single tag in the scroll view.

        \param inTag a UIImage of the tag to be displayed.
        \param inOffset the vertical offset (from the top of the display view) of the tag to be drawn.
    */
    func displayTag ( inTag:UIImage, inOffset:inout CGFloat )
    {
        let imageView:UIImageView = UIImageView ( image:inTag )
        var containerRect:CGRect = self.tagDisplayView!.frame   // See what we have to work with.
        containerRect.origin = CGPoint.zero
        let targetRect:CGRect = CGRect ( x: (containerRect.size.width - inTag.size.width) / 2.0, y: inOffset, width: inTag.size.width, height: inTag.size.height )
        imageView.frame = targetRect
        containerRect.size.height = max ( (targetRect.origin.y + targetRect.size.height), (containerRect.origin.y + containerRect.size.height) )
        self.tagDisplayView!.frame = containerRect
        self.tagDisplayView!.addSubview ( imageView )
        self.tagDisplayScroller!.contentSize = containerRect.size
        print ( "Tag Container Rect: \(containerRect)" )
        print ( "    Tag ScrollView Bounds: \(self.tagDisplayScroller!.bounds)" )
        inOffset = inOffset + (inTag.size.height * 0.31)
    }
```

Note that the scrollView's contentSize is expanded each time a tag is added. I checked (see the print statements), and the value seems to be correct.

[The project itself is completely open-source.](https://bitbucket.org/bmlt/nacc-ios-app)

[This is where this issue manifests](https://bitbucket.org/bmlt/nacc-ios-app/src/3025fc7f3589605f1e7ef28b4de392e83fcbc876/NACC-iOS/NACC_MainViewController.swift?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#NACC_MainViewController.swift-34) (I have other bugs, but I'll get around to fixing them after I nail this one).

I'm sure that I am doing something obvious and boneheaded (usually the case).

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I think the problem is with the uiview, you haven't set the height..

Comment: I'll check it out. The height is set (and removed at build time) in the storyboard, but I don't set it here. It's entirely possible that you are correct. I have found that undocumented (or not explicitly stated) things often change in OS upgrades. I've only been testing this in iOS 10. I wonder if it will work again in iOS 9? If so, I have another app that I'll need to adjust as well. Thanks!

Comment: Well, I just checked it out. Works in 9.3, but not in 10. The OS has introduced a curveball. The height is being set (see that I set the frame). I'll need to figure out why iOS 10 suddenly doesn't like this. I do almost exactly the same thing in another app, and I'm concerned.

Comment: I tried to set it in my end but it wasn't possible. Your UIView should have an explicit height. By testing i saw that 4-5 tags where working fine, and it scrolled, but if you had 20 you wouldn't be able to see them. So it's not as if your scroll view doesn't scroll..

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep poking at it. Like I said, it only happens when the device is iOS 10, so something changed under the hood. I've had this sort of thing happen before with other SDKs.

Comment: I just checked. My actual shipping app is doing the same thing in iOS 10. :(  That makes solving this a wee bit more urgent. I'll see if the Apple examples have anything different from what I do.

Comment: If i were you i would delete that View Controller and start again, set explicit height for your UIView and see how it goes..

Comment: Yeah, I think that I'll just rebuild the whole view. This is weird. The sample apps that Apple gives are: 1) in ObjC (not Swift), and 2) do exactly what I am doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK. I solved it.

I remove every single auto layout constraint for the internal (scrolled) view at build time.

I assume that iOS 10 is finally honoring the contract by forcing the top of the scrolled view to attach to the top of the scroller, even though the user wants to move it.

Comment: You remove every constraint at runtime and had success?  I'm seeing same issue except using Xamarin, where my UIScrollView no longer has a height after upgrading to IOS 10.  I can set up align vertically for my immediate child view and it shows but won't allow the scroll.   Removing the constraint in ViewDidLoad doesn't seem to effect it at all.

Comment: TBH, I haven't entirely figured this out. That worked for me in that instance. However, in other instances, I use the classic structure and it works. I need to spend some time trying stuff out.

Comment: I set up a demo Swift project to test this out. [This project](https://bitbucket.org/bmlt/testscroller) shows this in action. YMMV

Comment: In the end my issue seemed to be specific to Xamarin, when the xib was originally set up, for some reason the 'remove at build time' in xCode option was checked for my trailing and bottom constraint.   Looks like Xamarin was finally following that setting.

Comment: Glad you were able to get it worked out. I'm finding that using UITableView often makes a lot of this kind of thing easier. [This project](https://bitbucket.org/bmlt/bmltioslib) is still VERY green, but does demonstrate me using UITableView for complex UI layout (I have a test program I've written).

Answer (score 12):

it will work when you will set `contentSize` on main thread and put this code in `- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews`

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    dispatch_async (dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                    {
                        [self.scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(0, 2100)];
                    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the tip, and have given it a thumbs-up. Unfortunately, though absolutely correct, it was not the solution. The issue was that iOS 10 suddenly has started pinning scrolled views to the container if there are top and leading constraints. I had these removed at build time, and that solved it. Again, thanks.

Answer (score 8):

contentSize should be change in main thread in swift.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 2000, height: 2000)
    }
```

This worked for me.

Comment: This is working for me.. this is absolutely ridiculous this doesn't work from viewDidAppear

Comment: This also worked for me. One thing I have to mention is that it seems like the behavior is different on iPad as setting contentSize on the UI thread works just fine.